# What kind of wire can be used for CAN(Cotroller Area Network) protocol based communication?

Tags: wire, can, stm32f4

Is the wire used for CAN communication protocol any different or normal. Can normal wires(a pair for CAN LOW AND can HIGH)also be used for communication? I am looking to connect CAN controller 1 to CAN controller 2 in same STM32F407 board.

What kind of wire can be used for this purpose, will any wire be enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends entirely on the distance between the two controllers and the bit rate you have selected.

CAN is intended to work with twisted pair with a nominal impedance of 120 ohms. However, for lengths with a propagation delay of less than about 10% of the selected bit rate, impedance matching doesn't really matter much.

So for short runs (a few feet) almost any twisted pair will do. Regardless of bit rate and impedance considerations, twisted pair should always be used anyways in order to reduce EMI pickup. And depending on the electrical environment, shielded twisted pair is a really good idea, as well.